# Error running docker+html app:ERR Failed to resolve path: exec: "python3, './html2img.py": stat python3, './html2img.py: no such file or directory

Tags: python, html, docker, cloud-foundry, pcf

```
  2022-12-04T01:19:02.92-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/1] ERR Failed to resolve path: exec: "python3, './html2img.py": stat python3, './html2img.py: no such file or directory
```

Getting above error when dockerizing the python+html app.

I am deploying the dockerize(python + Html) app in PCF and getting the above error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey, I'm attempting to install a python + shell script application in our environment. I've dockerized the application, but my docker container won't start. if there are any additional steps I can take to deploy it?

Comment: Below is my docker file.
From nginx
WORKDIR /etc/nginx
COPY ./jota-cert-checker.sh ./jota-cert-checker.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./jota-cert-checker.sh", "/usr/share/nginx/html/certs_check.html"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Comment: And below is the python file.

#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Author        :Julio Sanz
Website       :www.elarraydejota.com
Email         :juliojosesb@gmail.com
Description   :Script to convert HTML to image
Dependencies  :Python 3.x, imgkit and wkhtmltopdf
Usage         :python3 html2img.py [html_filename] [img_filename]
License       :GPLv3
"""

import sys,imgkit

html_filename=sys.argv[1]
img_filename=sys.argv[2]

def convert_html2img():
 imgkit.from_file(html_filename, img_filename)


#
# MAIN
# 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    convert_html2img()